# DNODE PHP Fatal error: Class 'React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop'

Tags: php, composer-php, dnode

I am installing [dnode-php](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) from github repository.

I am running PHP 5.3.10 and Composer. I used the `composer.json` file included in the above repository to generate my `autoload.php` files.

When I go to run `server.php` I get the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'React\EventLoop\StreamSelectLoop' not found in /home/chelsea/dnode-php-master/examples/simple/server.php on line 16
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Changing it to "~0.2" did not solve the issue, it still spits out the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You want to download the React library for this. And then your issue will be solved out.